# selecting a list of files as build input

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

I would like to restrict the number of files to include in my build `src` to a select few.
Directly passing the list of files to `src` or `srcs` isn't allowed as an archive or a directory is expected.
I couldn't find a function to do this and `builtins.filterSource` does not seem to work for me (no idea why -- the intermediate derivation containing the filtered files ends up empty):

```
    files = [
        ./Cargo.toml
        ./Cargo.lock
        ./cpu.rs
    ];
    src = builtins.filterSource (p: t: builtins.elem p files) ./.;
```

Note: I'm using the `rustPlatform` builder but I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filterSource` passes the full path as a string.
in order to compare the paths of your list with it you need to convert the string to a path:

```sh
$ cd /Users/fghibellini/code/nix
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E './a == "/Users/fghibellini/code/nix/a"'
false
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E './a == (/. + "/Users/fghibellini/code/nix/a")'
true
```

i.e. the following code should work fine:

```
files = [
    ./Cargo.toml
    ./Cargo.lock
    ./cpu.rs
];
src = builtins.filterSource (p: t: builtins.elem (/. + p) files) ./.;
```

You can use `builtins.typeOf` and `builtins.trace` to debug such issues.

Comment: Damn! I've been the victim of universal equality, once more! I traced it and didn't think of the type...  Thanks!
Don't you think such a function should be part of the lib?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by such function, but
I think in this case I would blame the JavaScript-like conversion behaviour of strings/paths - it's quite a mess to work with.
even in the solution: Want to convert a string to a path? ...well obviously you just concatenate the root path with the string :/

Comment: I meant `builtins.filterSource (p: t: builtins.elem(/. + p) files) ./.`. But ideally `src` should accept a list of files in addition to directories and archives.

Comment: This is an underrated answer to an underrated question. Thank you for the `/. +` tip, and for the idea to take your include/exclude list as full paths as well, instead of trying to transform the paths passed to the filter function as relative.